# Typescript compiler, how to get the type of a symbol?

Tags: typescript-compiler-api

In need to get the type of a symbol, up until recently I was able to use:

```
const type = typeChecker.getTypeOfSymbolAtLocation(symbol, symbol.valueDeclaration);
console.log(typeChecker.typeToString(type));
```

However now it comes up as "any". What changed? What is the correct way of getting the information? Thanks!

This is how the symbol object looks like:

[image]

This is how the type object looks like:

[image]

Comment: Are there any diagnostics? Check `ts.getPreEmitDiagnostics(program)`

Comment: none comes up as an empty array. valueDeclaration seems to be undefined, but why? declarations is not empty.

Comment: Ok thanks. Could you provide more details in your question? (Ex. some code that this turns up `any` for or what is the `symbol` a symbol for) What you are doing should work.

Comment: Posted the symbol object, would that help? Otherwise I could try to make an isolated repro case.

Comment: Yeah, posting some code that reproduces it would be helpful. Or even, just posting a small example of the source code being analyzed and point out which symbol you have.